# Firebase Storage takes too long to upload video

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-storage

This is my first question in StackOverflow.

I am trying to upload video to Firebase Storage, but it takes too long to upload a file. I tested with a 30MB file that took 3-4 minutes to finish O_O and another 100MB video took 6-7 minutes.

I have an internet connection of 50Mb/sec (upload-download) so I expected it to be faster.

Note: I am using the latest versions of `firebase` and `file_picker`.

Is this a problem with Flutter or is there something I need to do?

```dart
  Future selectFile() async {
    final result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: false);
    if (result == null) return;
    final path = result.files.single.path;
    setState(() => file = File(path));
  }

  Future uploadFile() async {
    if (file == null) return;
    final fileName = basename(file.path);
    final destination = 'files/$fileName';
    task = FirebaseApi.uploadFile(destination, file);
    setState(() {});
    if (task == null) return;
    final snapshot = await task.whenComplete(() {});
    final urlDownload = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(currentUser.uid).update({
      'image1': urlDownload,
    });
  }


class FirebaseApi {
  static UploadTask uploadFile(String destination, File file) {
    try {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination);

      return ref.putFile(file);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance ^_^

Comment: I am using similar code as shown below and it takes approx 30 minutes to complete.  Any ideas?   Future<String> uploadFile({required File file}) async {
    final fileName = file.uri.pathSegments.last;
    final uuid = Uuid();
    final filePath = "videos/${uuid.v4()}_$fileName";
    debugPrint(filePath);
    final storage = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath);
    final uploadTask = storage.putFile(file);

    final snapshot = await uploadTask.whenComplete(() {});
    final downloadURL = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

    return downloadURL;
  }

Answer (score 1):

I think that's how it is. In my app, uploading a compressed imgae takes around 5- 6 seconds.

Have you ever tried to upload a video to an instant messaging app like WhatsApp? There, the upload isn't that fast either.

(Note: Are you sure you have 50 mBit/s in **upload** speed? That seems a lot to me)

Comment: the same tested video takes 2-3/sec in WhatsApp or any other messaging app like Messenger too, and yes my internet connection is 50Mb/sec AND even if it is not : a video with 50MB will never ever takes that mush of period, otherwise it will not takes shortly different period on WhatsApp !